# Will Time Machine restore the "Date Created" field along with the restored files?

Tags: mac, time-machine, metadata

If I use Time Machine to backup my Mac and then have to restore it later, will it retain the "Date Created" attribute of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that it does on OS X 10.9. I created a spreadsheet in November 2013, then deleted it a couple of weeks back. I've just restored it (because I didn't know the answer to this question!) and the Date Created says 17 November 2013.

Since Time Machine changes between OS X versions, I can't say that this will be the case for older versions, but I imagine it should be.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that the Date Created field is the most important attribute of a file and this is a make or break if I decide to use OS X over Windows 8 in the future (Microsoft will have to pry Windows 7 from my cold, dead hands first).

Comment: what about "date added" field?